# Access secret from firestore triggered cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I'm using Googles Secret Manager for accessing secrets in my cloud functions. This was working fine until now for all my functions - that are https and pubsub functions.
Now I wrote a function that gets triggered by a firestore document change:

```
exports.onDocumentUpdated = functions
  .runWith({ secrets: ["MY_SECRET"] })
  .firestore
  .document('documents/{documentId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change: func.Change<QueryDocumentSnapshot>, context)
```

In this case process.env.MY_SECRET is undefined. When I look up the secrets of the functions in the Cloud Console I see that it has access to a completely different secret that I'm using in another function. When adding MY_SECRET here the cloud functions work, but only until I redeploy via cli - then MY_SECRET is again removed.

I checked the permissions of the other secrets, all of them show exactly the same Roles/Principals. It's literally all the same the only difference is that this function is a firestore trigger function. What am I missing?

*Edit:
Did another test with following two functions:*

```
exports.testSecret1 = functions
  .runWith({ secrets: ["TEST_SECRET"] })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    func.logger.info(`${process.env.TEST_SECRET}`);
  })

exports.testSecret2 = functions
  .runWith({ secrets: ["TEST_SECRET"] })
  .firestore
  .document('documents/{documentId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change: func.Change<QueryDocumentSnapshot>, context) => {
    func.logger.info(`${process.env.TEST_SECRET}`);
  })
```

`testSecret1` has access to `TEST_SECRET`
`testSecret2` has no access to `TEST_SECRET`, prints undefined

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command to give access to your secret `TEST_SECRET`

```
firebase functions:secrets:access TEST_SECRET
```

If you are newly creating secrets use the following command

```
firebase functions:secrets:set SECRET_NAME
```

Before deploying, make sure your functions code allows the function to access the secret using the `runWith` parameter.

Check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#create-secret) for more information.

Also make sure that you are using latest version of `firebase-tools`